# Domain attached file server not authenticating with DC

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I have 2 servers:

Domain controller (Windows server 2012 std) - 192.168.1.2 Name dcsrv01

File server (Windows server 2012 std) - 192.168.2.2 Name fsrv01

The file server is domain attached.

The two are linked together over a site to site VPN. The DC has a network share called 'Shared'. When I log on to the file server using a domain admin account, and try to access \dcsrv01\Shared, it still brings up a username and password box, although I have logged in as a domain admin.

It does this with every PC on the fsrv01 network. Anything on the internal LAN it is working fine.

Any ideas why this is? I am putting it down to DNS, although I can't pin point the solution.

The file servers primary DNS server is the DC.

Thanks

Comment: Can you ping the DC/DNS server?  Can you do NSLookups against the DC/DNS server?  Is the file server on the other side of the site to site tunnel a domain member?

Comment: If you enter the creds requested, do you gain access to the share?